# How to set dynamic date value in json file in java/kotlin

Tags: java, json, kotlin

I have one JSON file. I'm using this file for integration test scenarios. I have one field named `end_date` in this file, and I want its value to be dynamic, such as 'end_date = current_date + 30 days'. How can I pass this in a JSON file? Using any regex pattern, or another solution?

```
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "priority": 1,
      "request": {
        "urlPath": "/some_url",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "authorization": {
            "matches": "Some auth token"
          }
        },
        "bodyPatterns": [
          {
            "equalToJson": {
              "name": "TEST DBA",
              "send_choice": "both",
              "email": "firstName.lastname@gmail.com",
              "phone" : "1234567890",
              "country": "us",
              "language": "en-us",
              "end_date" : "2024-01-23",
              "reference": "TEST_REFERENCE_ID"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "response": {
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "status": 200,
        "body": "{\"link\": \"http://www.some_response.com\",\"id\": \"TEST_ID\",\"reference\": \"TEST_REFERENCE_ID\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you mean something like this? "end_date" : "$END_DATE",

Comment: yes. but its not working

Comment: It will only work if you write some code to interpret whatever special symbols you put in the JSON, which will need to replace your encoding with whatever dates they mean in the final program. The work to be done is not really in the JSON, but in the code.

Comment: JSON is not a dynamic format. It's basically all up to what the software you use does with it.

Comment: Yes correct, I tried with code as well, but was getting some issues there as well.
I got one more solution. We can use like below, it worked. 
"end_date" : "${json-unit.any-string}",